# Python module to deb package

Tags: debian, python, debian-installer, deb, python3

I am trying to package `numpy 1.12.1` into deb package. In order to do that first I run

```
dh_make -f ../numpy1.12.1.tar.gz
```

and it generates a `debian` directory, in the `control` file generated it shows `numpyBROKEN`, I change that to numpy1.12.1 and edit `debian/rules` to tell that this package has a `setup.py` file and must be compiled with `python3`. This is my `debian/rules` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# See debhelper(7) (uncomment to enable)
# output every command that modifies files on the build system.
#DH_VERBOSE = 1

# see EXAMPLES in dpkg-buildflags(1) and read /usr/share/dpkg/*
DPKG_EXPORT_BUILDFLAGS = 1
include /usr/share/dpkg/default.mk

# see FEATURE AREAS in dpkg-buildflags(1)
#export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS = hardening=+all

# see ENVIRONMENT in dpkg-buildflags(1)
# package maintainers to append CFLAGS
#export DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND  = -Wall -pedantic
# package maintainers to append LDFLAGS
#export DEB_LDFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND = -Wl,--as-needed


# main packaging script based on dh7 syntax
%:
        dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild

# debmake generated override targets
# This is example for Cmake (See http://bugs.debian.org/641051 )
#override_dh_auto_configure:
#       dh_auto_configure -- \
#       -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)
```

Then I run:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

and it generates a package. But if I unpack the deb package or if I watch the structure folder generated by `dpkg-buildpackage` I only can see the following

```
$ ls debian/numpy1.12.1
DEBIAN  usr
$ ls debian/numpy1.12.1/DEBIAN/
control  md5sums
$ ls debian/numpy1.12.1/usr/
share
$ ls debian/numpy1.12.1/usr/share/doc/numpy1.12.1/
changelog.Debian.gz  copyright
```

Only the `DEBIAN` files and in `usr` folder only appear `share` folder nothing about the numpy compiled files...

How can I generate a debian package from python module?

Comment: Unfortunately, dh_make is unlikely to be useful on a complicated package like numpy. As it happens, 1.12.1 is already packaged in the jessie-backports repository. Why don't you use this? :)

Comment: Because I am compiling for raspberry pi and for python3.6 (python3.6 isn't in the oficial repository). I have needed to compile python3.6 and I want to distribute a numpy deb for my python compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel?

```
dget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python-numpy/python-numpy_1.12.0-2.dsc
cd python-numpy-1.12.0
```

Check PY3VERS in `debian/rules` then rebuild:

```
dch -n "Rebuild with Python 3.6."
dch -r ignored
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```